# Use varchar or Char For encrypted Salt?

Tags: php, mysql

It has always puzzled me with the creation of my Databases. What would be the correct data type for my Encrypted with md5 salt password?

I've been using VarChar; but i've been told to move over to `char` but never given an explination?

Which also, I know it's not in best practice but i've got my database as Varchar(255) to hold my password; What would also be the best length to have it? because I don't know for certain if md5 always returns the same length string, or it can vary?

Comment: MD5 is broken. you know that right?

Comment: An MD5 hash is typically expressed as a hexadecimal number, 32 digits long.

Comment: @MitchWheat Explain what you mean by Broken?

Comment: its no longer considered secure as it can be broken with rainbow tables (pre-hashed passwords) to see which hash match what password. Using a salt of course will prevent that or at least make it much more difficult to use a rainbow table against.

Comment: "In December 2008, a group of researchers used this technique to fake SSL certificate validity,[7][8] and US-CERT now says that MD5 "should be considered cryptographically broken and unsuitable for further use",[9] and most U.S. government applications now require the SHA-2 family of hash functions.[10]"

Comment: The SSL MD5 hashing was done using an array of Playstation 3 and all it did was find an MD5 collision when signing the key so they could make a CA cert that looked legitimately signed. This is different from hashing a password with a salt as they just looked for a collision, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're first question:

> VARCHAR
>
> - Trailing white space is preserved. (MySQL 5.0.3+ only.)
> - Minimal storage overhead. A 17 character record takes up only 17 characters of space.
> - Slower SELECTs when searching this column.
>
> CHAR
>
> - Trailing white space is always removed.
> - Every record takes up a fixed amount of space - 19 characters in your case. Your 17 character records will waste two bytes of storage.
> - Faster SELECTs when searching this column.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Comment: so do indeed use char over varchar?

Comment: if you know your string length is always fixed then use char, otherwise use varchar. if your not sure use varchar, and the differences are minimal anyway.

Comment: It all really depends on the situation. VARCHAR is more/less for databases you know are going to have a lot of entries. CHAR is for when you don't really care.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 will always return 32 chars so using CHAR(32) would be more efficient when storing, even if it uses a salt it will still hash out to that many chars. You always want to choose the most appropriate char size.

Comment: This answers part two of my question, but how about part 1? whats the difference between VarChar and Char in the mysql data types?

Comment: @user1902584 difference explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html you will save 1byte using char-32 over varchar-32 if you are always storing a 32 char string. being 1 whole byte, its not uncommon to see this distinction being completely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you going to change your password salting - what not change the encryption at the same time to something secure - [like bcyrpt.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

It seems like a wasted effort to try and 'fine tune' a md5 setup, [when md5 is compromised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security)

In regards to other your part of the question;

```
> A CHAR(x) column can only have exactly x characters. 
> A VARCHAR(x)column can have up to x characters.
```

So if you salt is 'fixed' (i.e. always 6 chars) - then you want "CHAR" for better performane. But if your salt is variable (i.e. 5-6 chars) - then you have to use VARCHAR.